# react uploaded file needs to be re-uploaded in order to be detected

Tags: reactjs

```
import React from 'react'
import {useState} from 'react'

const Upload = () => {
    const [song, setSong] = useState({
        title: '',
        audio_file: null,
        genre: '',
    })

    const [audio, setAudio] = useState(null)

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        const newState = { ...song, [e.target.name]: e.target.value}
        setSong(newState)
    }

    const handleAudio = (e) => {  // putting file into audio, then putting it in song
        setAudio(e.target.files[0])
        setSong({audio_file: audio})
    }

    const uploadSong = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        console.log(song)
    }

    return (
    <>
        <form onSubmit={uploadSong}>
            <section className="upload">
                <div className="upload-content">
                    <h4>Upload Music</h4>
                    <input type="file" name="music" id='song' className='hidden'  onChange={handleAudio}/>
                    <label for='song' className='btn'>Select Music</label>
                </div>
            </section>

            <section className="info">
                <div className="info-content">
                    <h2>Upload Info</h2>
                    <div className="info-visual">
                        <div className="info-single">
                            <p>Audio File</p>
                            {audio ? <p className='green'>{audio.name}</p> : <i className='fas fa-times' />}
                        </div>

                        <div className="info-single">
                            <p>Title {song.title ? <i className='fas fa-check' /> : <i className='fas fa-times' /> }</p>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter a Title..." name='title' onChange={handleChange}/>
                        </div>

                        <div className="info-single">
                            <p>Size</p>
                            {audio ? <p class='green'>{`${(audio.size / 1000000).toString().substr(0,3)} MB`}</p> : <i className='fas fa-times' />}
                        </div>

                        <div className="info-single">
                            <p>Genre {song.genre ? <i className='fas fa-check' /> : <i className='fas fa-times' />}</p>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter a Genre..." name='genre' onChange={handleChange}/>
                        </div>
                        {song.title && audio.lenght > 0 && song.genre ? 
                        <button className="btn" type='submit'>Continue</button> : <button className="btn green">Please fill in the fields</button>}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        </form>
    </>
    )
}

export default Upload
```

> Basically when I try to upload the file (which is sent to {audio} and then {song} in the {handleAudio} function) and fill in the fields the button doesn't change accordingly but when I re-upload the file it gets inserted in the {song} object located at the very top and the button changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should the the following:

```
    setAudio(e.target.files[0])
    setSong({audio_file: e.target.files[0]})
```

due to how react works if you do setAudio the value will not change until the component re render again
so access it will be wrong cause you get the previous value.
think about this

useState -> re-render -> state is updated with the new value

this is also the reason why only after re-insert you get the new value

For your information:
React 18 will introduce a new  feature call batch update the will update your start with a group of useState and not only one by one